# UIPageviewController PDF

Tags: iphone, pdf, ios5, uiwebview, uipageviewcontroller

I am new to iphone app developing and need to display a PDF file in an app that I am working on. I would like to use UIPageViewController as that allows paging ect. As of yet I have not been able to figure out how to load the content into a UIWebview and still get the paging function. If there is a better way to implement it without using UIWebview that is fine too. I would just like to use it because it is a bit easier, but it is not a necessity. If someone could point me to any sample code or any tips that would help me I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple has a sample code project called `ZoomingPDFReader`. It's a simple app that displays a page of a PDF. Put this into your app. Keep track of the page number, and then display the corresponding PDF page.

---

**You can download the source code [here](https://github.com/jackhumphries/UIPageViewController-PDF).**

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am very new to all this and I just don't quite have it yet. How would I tell it to find the next page and load it into the pageviewcontroller? I know this is a stupid question, but I'm just trying to learn... :-)

Comment: Here's a link to a working project: https://www.chillysky.com/UIPageViewControllerDemo.zip. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: The source code has been moved to https://github.com/jackhumphries/UIPageViewController-PDF.